# Multiple Where clause is not working on fire-store fire-base query using java-script code

Tags: javascript, jquery, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

[image]

```
 db.collection('User_Info').where("User_Name", "==", "Sam").where("PASSWORD", "==", "c2FtMTIzQA==").get().then(snapshot => {
if(snapshot.docs.length > 0 ){
    debugger;
    alert("Login Successful.");
    snapshot.docs.forEach(doc => {
        var text = doc.data().name;
        var value = doc.id;         
        console.log("First Log Data" + doc.data());
    }); 
  } 
});
```

The above code i am using to check the username and password into User_Info Table in my fire-base fire store database.

I tried to check with debugger but it won't working. it cannot debug the code just jump out from the code.

What is the major problem here ? anyone can help me ? having knowledge of fire base compound query's must be good.

Comment: Are you getting any errors? Or unexpected behaviour?

Comment: No any errors found just goes out the control

Comment: Please add your database structure and please also responde with @AlexMamo

Comment: @AlexMamo hello Alex thanks for replaying me back. i just edited my question with image please check it .Waiting for your solution. because i am stuck on this for 3 days !

Comment: Does this line `console.log("First Log Data" + doc.data());` print something?

Comment: @AlexMamo Its printing data of return object. when i have used only user name checked !

Answer (score 0):

add .catch and check what is the error, you might need to add some indexes